# SoundCloud API: Getting the likes for a given user

Tags: java, soundcloud

I am using the SoundCloud API and I've noticed a difference between the number of likes on the website and the number of likes given by the API.

For example:

```
HTTPResponse resptest = wrapper.get(Request.to("/users/4132982/favorites?limit=200");
```

gives 133 likes. The [soundcloud public profile](https://soundcloud.com/ariteufeur)  for that user has 141 likes. Does anybody have an idea of what the problem is?

"This was tagged, as a duplicate. It has nothing related to the other question."

Comment: Agreed that this is strange.  I wasn't able to reproduce this on my personal account.  I did find two additional behaviors I didn't expect 1) favorited private tracks are included in this number and 2) deleted tracks are included with no way to undo it.

Comment: Could it have something to do with vote fuzzing? I am unfamilar with soundcloud and if the likes have any weight on anything.

Comment: Given SoundCloud's troubles, this question could be moot soon.